# Set caret position on JScrollPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, caret

I have a JEditoPane inside a JScrollPane.  I have some text content that contain some pre-defined tokens. I'm storing the location of these tokens in the database.
When I set the text content into the JEditorPane, I embed the tokens with HTML.  I also add HTML break lines to format the content.

Now problem comes when I want to scroll to one of the highlighted tokens.  It seems that  the start position of the tokens, which I stored in database,  do not match when using the setCaretPosition(int).  I know it's probably because my content in JEditorPane Document is mixed with HTML.

So is there a way to search for a String in the JEditorPane content, then somehow get the caret position where the string was found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the strings have any commonalities? If they do, you could try using a combination of the java.util.scanner or/and java.util.regex.Matcher. Make sure to get the right regex for what you need. Once you have found a string get the indexOf the first letter and set the caret position to it.

[Java Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

[Java Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Answer (score 1):

That's how you do it (ignore not using best practices ;) ) -

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    final JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane( "text/html", "<h1>This is some header</h1>After this text would be the CARRET<br>This is some more text<br>And more" );
    final JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane( jEditorPane );

    final JFrame jframe = new JFrame( "HHHHHH" );
    jframe.add( jScrollPane );
    jframe.setSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
    jframe.setVisible( true );

    final String text = jEditorPane.getText();
    final int index = text.indexOf( "T" );
    jEditorPane.setCaretPosition( index + 1 );

    while ( true ) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 1000000 );
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the result:

[image]

You should store the result of `indexof` in the DB.